# Where did the "calmly eating noodles when bad guys walk in" scene first appear?

Tags: film-techniques, first-appearance

This scene happens in many martial arts movies:

It usually starts with some hero wandering into a strange town; orders a bowl of noodles; then a couple of bad guys casually sit down and start harassing the hero because he/she appears weak; this is then followed by the hero beating every bad guy in town and casually walking out of the restaurant.

One recent [example of this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n4YUJ8Lxrqs) is with Zhang Ziyi in Crouching Tiger Hidden Dragon.

The opening scene of Kung Fu Panda also has [a similar scene](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zr9upB3D67s).

So what is the reference for this scene? When did it first appear? How did it become popularised? What is its country of origin?

Comment: It sort of parallels the western where the new stranger in town goes to the bar and orders a glass of milk...

Answer (score 11):

This theme is not limited to martial arts movies and makes an appearance in many movie genres. The eating a bowl of noodles can easily be traded out with having a beer in a saloon from any number of westerns.

This device has occurs constantly in westerns. See this clip from a 1939 western: